# PyCharm - Python Strange behavior

Tags: python, pycharm

I dont know if I can post this here or not. But a strange thing happened recently.

I use pycharm to run my python codes and surprisingly when I opened a piece of my code - it got deleted. The file is 0KB now - for some reason. I am using this file for over a month now and this happened when I opened it and the file automatically got deleted from pycharm and next it became 0KB.

When I tried to delete this file:

I get the following

Error 0xx800710FE: This file is currently not available for use on this computer

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm has Local History feature, it might recover your deleted file...

- Right click on your file
- Click `Local History`
- Click `Show History`

  [image]
- Right Click on the time-frame you'd like to go back to and click `Revert`

  [image]

Comment: I am on Windows 7 so the show history is under VCS --> Local History -- > Show history. But it is only showing me the editions I have done in the main file. The file I lost has a function which being used by my main function. The file is still on my folder - with ZERO KB and I cant move it nor delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a problem with one of my network servers. It is fixed after talking with an IT professional